# Issue outputting/detecting NDI with FFmpeg 3.4

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm having issues with the Newtek/NDI functionality added to FFmpeg 3.4, running on Ubuntu Server 16.04.3. I've downloaded the Newtek SDK, added and linked the appropriate lib files to usr/lib, and I'm compiling with the options:

> --enable-libndi_newtek --extra-cflags="-I/home/user/ffmpeg_build/ndi/include" --extra-ldflags="L/home/user/ffmpeg_build/ndi/include"

When I run the command as detailed on the FFmpeg site to detect an NDI stream it fails to do so. Similarly when encoding to an NDI stream, it cannot be detected either on the network or from the same machine. Has anyone successfully encoded an NDI stream with FFmpeg, and if so can anyone give me any information on I'm likely doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the avahi-daemon package to allow usage of mDNS.